# How can I use a method in one class to create an instance of another in Java?

Tags: java, initialization

I have two classes, one that is a computational object (CyberPet.java) and the other that tests the computational one (TestCyberPet.java). In the TestCyberPet, I have a method called createPet() that will use user input to instantiate an instance of CyberPet. I've already done

```
CyberPet pet3 = null;
```

This is createPet():

```
   private static CyberPet createPet()
   {
        /*** Local variables ***/

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );

        final String formatString = "%22s: ";

        String name;
        String size;
        String activity;

        /*** Get user input ***/

        System.out.println();
        System.out.printf( formatString, "Enter your pet's name" );
        name = scanner.nextLine().trim();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.printf( formatString, "Enter your pet's size (big or small)" );
        size = scanner.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.printf( formatString, "Enter your pet's current activity (eating, sleeping, or thinking)" );
        activity = scanner.nextLine().trim().toLowerCase();

        /*** Validate input, notify user of errors ***/

        if ( name.length() == 0 )
        {
            System.out.println( "   Invalid input. Name cannot be blank." );
            name = CyberPet.DEFAULT_NAME;
        }

        // else leave as entered string

        if ( size == "big" || size == "small" )
        {
            System.out.println( "   Invalid input. Size must be either big or small." );
            size = CyberPet.DEFAULT_SIZE;
        }

        // else leave as entered string

        if ( activity == "eating" || activity == "sleeping" || activity == "thinking" )
        {
            System.out.println( "   Invalid input. Activity must be eating, sleeping, or thinking." );
            activity = CyberPet.DEFAULT_ACTIVITY;
        }

        // else leave as entered string

        /*** Create cyberpet ***/

        CyberPet pet = new CyberPet( name, size, activity );
        return pet;
    }
```

I've got it working (I think!) up until I try to do this

```
pet3.createPet();
```

Because createPet isn't in the CyberPet class to use it there. How can I use createPet to create an instance of CyberPet?

I hope I put enough information in here... This is my first post on StackOverflow, so if I need to add anything more, just tell me! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that you've got a bit of a mixed up understanding of how these classes should be.

If you're creating a test object, then you shouldn't need user input. You should just use known values. It's quicker and serves the same purpose. Secondly, if you want to access a `private static` method, then you need to do so from within the class. It can be accessed via:

```
TestCyberPet.createPet();
```

This will return an instance of type `CyberPet`.

**Note**

- Firstly, you need to look at [testing frameworks like JUnit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JUnit). This automates the testing process for you and makes it easier to write these sorts of tests.
- Secondly, revise your knowledge of OOP. You should not be performing validation of user input for a class, outside of that class. Only the class itself should know what it needs.